# Json Cpp isMember() Returns True always

Tags: c++, json

For example in a simple json

```
{
    "A" :
    {
       "B" :
       {
         --something--
       }
    }
}
```

### First Case:

```
json::Value root;
const Json::Value x = root["A"]["B"];
if (root.isMember("A")) --- always returns TRUE..
```

### Second Case:

```
Json::Value root;
If (root.isMember("A"))  ---- works fine
const Json::Value x = root["A"]["B"];
```

Any idea what's wrong with First Case? even if I get `x` before `isMember()` call.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at [documentation](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_value.html).

```
Value &     operator[] (const char *key)
    Access an object value by name, create a null member if it does not exist. 
const Value &   operator[] (const char *key) const
    Access an object value by name, returns null if there is no member with that name. 
Value &     operator[] (const std::string &key)
    Access an object value by name, create a null member if it does not exist. 
const Value &   operator[] (const std::string &key) const
    Access an object value by name, returns null if there is no member with that name.
```

Basically, you are creating the member `"A"` on `root["A"]` call. To avoid this always check  `isMember` before actually accessing the member (or call it only on `const` object and do a null check instead - I'd preffer the former).

Comment: This is the standard behavior in STL map as well.